# How can I read a text file in .Net Standard version 1.0 or 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, readfile, .net-standard

I want to read the contents of a text file.

Is this possible in .Net Standard 1.0 or 1.1?

```
File.ReadAllLines("...");
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your project file?

Comment: why not try it out?

Comment: Honestly, you simply shouldn't even be using .NET Standard 1.0 or 1.1 any more; they are both long since redundant except as migration tools; even .NET Standard 2.0 is kinda "eh, I wouldn't touch that now"; there *may* be a case for .NET Standard 2.1, but honestly most of the time I'd say "target an actual runtime, or multiple runtimes". Is there an actual reason you want to target .NET Standard 1.0 or 1.1? I'd be very tempted to say "challenge that requirement"

Comment: Already posted by someone a few weeks ago... but there is no solution.

Comment: @gunr2171 it's an empty "Class library" project with <TargetFramework>netstandard1.1</TargetFramework>
It has no implementation and no code!

Comment: why don't you update the .NET standard version 1.0 to 1.3 . the 1.3 contains such implementations you are trying to run

Comment: @MarcGravell In our company exist many projects with different dot net versions.
For example, old projects use dot net framework 4.5 and new projects use dot net core 5.
I was looking for a way to manage all these projects with one library.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the dot net version of old projects, it costs a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: NO

Check this link [File class in net standard 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-1.1)

[image]

Why not go to [1.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netstandard-1.3)? You shouldn't have any breaking compatibility issues. I don't see any work arounds that are easy to implement.

You can also check [compatibility table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) to see if you can use the version without any issue, based on the framework where you want to consume the library.

Comment: I need it for projects that use version dot net framework 4.5.
OKay: Long story short: NO.
Thanks :), it's not possible

Comment: Check the API https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.1_ref.md there is no IO component available.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not possible to read the file in versions 1.0 to 1.3. Thankful.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I needed to use a library for all projects with different dot net versions like dot net framework 4.5 and dot net core 5.

The `TargetFrameworks` in my project `".csproj file"` was as follows:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.0;netstandard1.1;netstandard1.2;netstandard1.3;netstandard1.4;netstandard1.5;netstandard1.6;netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

I had to use it as follows:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net45;net451;net452;netstandard1.3;netstandard1.4;netstandard1.5;netstandard1.6;netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

My problem was solved.